# Not able to get element by id in DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am trying to scroll to a row with a specific id in DataTable. following is the code for it.

```
function scroll_row(int_id) {
    var obj_element = document.getElementById(int_id);
    if(obj_element != null) {
        var int_scroll_pos = obj_element.offsetTop;
        $('#myTable').parent().scrollTop(int_scroll_pos-10);
    } 
}
```

But the problem with this is that the `obj_element` is giving me null while getting it by id.

For example if I have 50 rows in my data-table and I try to give the id of the 40th element while scroll being at the top it returns me null.

But when I scroll down somewhere near to that element. It returns the value for getElementById as it should.

I don't know what's the problem here. Anyone knows about this?

I also tried it doing this way https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/33/using-fngetposition-to-find-a-tr-by-id

```
$("#myTable").fnGetPosition(document.getElementById("262617"))
```

but in this case also it says fnGetPosition is not a function.

This is how my datatable is

```
tableSettings = {

... 

}

var myTable = $('#myTable').DataTable(tableSettings);
```

I am not able to understand what is happening in both the cases I mentioned. Hoping to get some help. Thanks :)

Edit - Adding an image with example

[image with html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUiN0.png)

The one with id = 140876 is the last tr row of the datatable. If I'm scrolled up top to the first element of the datatable and try document.getElementById("140876") it gives me null. But I get the value if I'm scrolled down to the bottom. Same goes for every other row. The rows down are returning null when I'm scrolled up.

P.S. had to remove the first image as right now I'm only allowed to add 1 link.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the generated HTML markup, please ?

Comment: I am not really sure what you need. I have taken a screenshot for fnGetPosition error. In other case when I console log getElement by id for example 40th element. It gives null. Until I scroll the data-table down to the 40th element. I hope I'm not confusing. :)

Comment: Without the HTML generated by `DataTables`, we cannot see if rows contains the `id`you are expecting. The only reason that you don't get anything when requesting an `id` is because it is not present in the code generated by `DataTables`.

Comment: Ohh ok. By the way it does have the id's I'm looking for. But I'll add an image to give an example.

Answer (score 0):

To use `fnGetPosition`, you should use it like this:

```
var table = $('#myTable').dataTable(); // with a lower 'd'
var row_index = table.fnGetPosition(this)[0];
```

Here is a working example: http://live.datatables.net/xoqidaqi/1/

It's a corrected version of the faulty example found here: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/21582/fngetposition-undefined

Comment: I can't change DataTable to dataTable many of the other things that I have already used won't work. Is there any other way around this?

Comment: The code I posted is intended to replace this call `$("#myTable").fnGetPosition(document.getElementById("262617"))`. Using `DataTables`with an upper `D` is to instantiate the datatable with settings. Using `dataTable`with a lower `d` is to retreive the instantiated datatable.

Comment: It is still giving me error TypeError: a.nodeName is undefined
...osition=function(a){var b=this.api(!0),c=a.nodeName.toUpperCase();return"TR"==c?...

Comment: This my new functio now - `function scroll_row(int_id) { var table = $('#myTable').dataTable(); 
 var row_index = table.fnGetPosition(this)[0];
 console.log(row_index);
 if(row_index != null) {
  var int_scroll_pos = row_index.offsetTop;
  $('#myTable').parent().scrollTop(int_scroll_pos-10);
 } }  ` Rest of things are same as earlier

Comment: Tried doing this also. `var row_index = table.fnGetPosition( $("#"+int_id))[0];` But this also gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You will get the first/all column value of the table.
Assign `tr` class on `tr` in the body tag of the table.
The column will be changed according to the number in `eq(0)` for the first column / `eq(1)` for the second column and so on.

```
var table=$('#ID_OF_THE_TABLE').DataTable();

table.$('.bodytr').each(function()  
{ 
 console.log((this).find("td").eq(0).html());
});
```